# How can I share the contents of my page in iPhone app on facebook?

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm providing a facebook share option on my iPhone app screen and need to share some images and URL on the user's facebook profile . I know there are several third party frameworks like ShareKit and other features like facebook sdk for iOS, but which is the best way I could so the same and i need to get the share button with the number of shares until now as shown in the image below

[image]

and on clicking should redirect to authentication.
And should be compatible with iOS5 and above, hope my question is clear.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the question myself through research

I used Facebook `Graph API` since my application needs support from `iOS4`+, would have been simple if it was for iOS6 as `iOS6` has Facebook integration and needs just a few lines of code to implement it.
 Imported `Graph APi` files and added the following code:

```
@synthesize facebook;

//login with facebook
- (IBAction) facebookButtonPressed {
    if (!facebook || ![facebook isSessionValid]) {
        self.facebook = [[[Facebook alloc] init] autorelease];
        NSArray *perms = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"read_stream", @"create_note", nil];
        [facebook authorize:FACEBOOK_API_KEY permissions:perms delegate:self];
    }
    else {
        [self fbDidLogin];
    }
}

//upload image once you're logged in
-(void) fbDidLogin {
    [self fbUploadImage];
}

- (void) fbUploadImage
{
    NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    resultImage, @"picture",
                                    nil];
    [facebook requestWithMethodName: @"photos.upload" 
                          andParams: params
                      andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                        andDelegate: self]; 

    self.currentAlertView = [[[UIAlertView alloc]
                             initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook", @"")  
                             message:NSLocalizedString(@"Uploading to Facebook.", @"")  
                             delegate:self 
                             cancelButtonTitle:nil
                             otherButtonTitles: nil] autorelease];

    [self.currentAlertView show];
}

//facebook error
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didFailWithError:(NSError*)error
{

    [self.currentAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.currentAlertView = nil;

    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Error", @"")  
                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook error message", @"")
                            delegate:self 
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}

//facebook success
- (void)request:(FBRequest*)request didLoad:(id)result
{
    [self.currentAlertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:YES];
    self.currentAlertView = nil;

    UIAlertView *myAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                            initWithTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"Facebook", @"") 
                            message:NSLocalizedString(@"Uploaded to Facebook message", @"")
                            delegate:self 
                            cancelButtonTitle:nil
                            otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [myAlert show];
    [myAlert release];
}
```

And to get the share count of a particular URL in facebook,
 use

```
http://graph.facebook.com/?id=url
```

But this returns the count of all likes,shares and posts altogether, so better find some alternatives to do so.

Hope this helps
Thanks